# H2 database issue for Junit test cases

Tags: hibernate, junit, h2

Hi I have query like below that I am executing from hibernate:

```sql
SELECT english.locale as "locale", english.resource_key as "resourceKey",english.validity_check as "validityCheck",null AS "text" FROM  
(SELECT * FROM i18n.dictionary_message enMessage  WHERE enMessage.locale = 'en_GB') english  
left JOIN  (SELECT * FROM i18n.dictionary_message localeMessage WHERE localeMessage.locale = 'de_DE') innerLocale 
 ON english.resource_key = innerLocale.resource_key  WHERE innerLocale.locale IS NULL  
 UNION  
 SELECT outerLocale.locale as "locale", outerLocale.resource_key as "resourceKey", outerLocale.validity_check as "validityCheck", outerLocale.text AS "text"  
 FROM i18n.dictionary_message outerLocale  left JOIN  i18n.dictionary_message innerEnMessage ON innerEnMessage.resource_key = outerLocale.resource_key  AND innerEnMessage.locale = 'en_GB'  WHERE outerLocale.locale = 'de_DE'  ORDER BY  english.resource_key  ASC
```

This native query is working fine when the record fetch from UI (through application) but failing when I am trying to write unit cases for this for order by clause, error is

> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Order by expression "ENGLISH.RESOURCE_KEY" must be in the result list in this case"

for Unit test cases H2 database used and for actual application MSSQL server. I think the problem is happening due to H2 DB, can anyone please help if they encountered similar kind of issue?

Comment: Use the same database for testing and production

Comment: I think it is not possible because for all other test cases we are using H2 only, and for this particular test it wont be allowed

Comment: Try using mssql compatibility mode http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility other then that not much you can do, databases have different syntax and a query that works on mssql doesn't have to work on h2

Comment: I tried but didn't work, thanks anyways for the help

Comment: problem resolved by using column number in query..